# How long would it take to hike from Hamar to Lillehammer?

Tags: hiking, norway

I'm considering a trip to Norway, and I'd like to hike for part of it.

For background, my girlfriend and I would like to see Oslo and Trondheim (as our top choices), so my thought was to train from Oslo to Hamar and hike from Hamar to Lillehammer along St. Olav's Way and then take the train from Lillehammer to Trondheim.

Google says it's about 60 km (37 mi) from Hamar to Lillehammer. 13 km a day seems like a doable goal. But hiking time is dependent on elevation change, and trail conditions, so **considering the terrain in that area, how long would it take to hike?**

We're in decent shape right now, but could easily train up before going.

We'd like to go in early May.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, both Hamar and Lillehammer are located at the Lake Mjøsa, so there will be no net elevation change along the way. The pilgrim's path does not follow the shore though, so there are some light to moderate inclines along the way, but always accompanied with following descents.

Except from telling you that, noone here will be able to tell you which pace you prefer or can manage. Even being less than in 'decent shape', hiking 25-30km a day should IMHO be easily feasible in such light terrain.

The ['official' information page on this section](http://pilegrimsleden.no/en/suggestions/hedmarken-fra-hamar-til-lillehammer) of the pilgrim's road suggests that you use four days,

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the sort of information I was looking for. I read that it should be relatively snow-free by June, how snowy would it be in May? Enough to need any snow boots/clothes, etc?

Comment: Weather next year is of course also impossible to predict, but you are not likely to find snow in that area in May.